# Normalizing a list of names

Tags: python, list

I made this code to normalize a list of names:

```
n  = ['King ARTHUR',
      'Lancelot The brave',
      'galahad the  pure',
      'Servant  patsy',
      'GALAHAD THE PURE']

for x in n:
    lw = x.lower()
    for i in lw.split():
        n2.append(i)
for i in n2:
    if i == 'the' :
        i.lower()
        n3.append(i)
    else:
        i.capitalize()
        n3.append(i)
print(n3)
```

The objective of the code is to eliminate extra spaces, duplicates, and make the first letter of each of the knights names and titles capitalized while "the" is lowercase.
However the output seems to ignore the `.capitalize()` command.
Any idea what's missing?

Comment: Try `i = i.lower()` and i = `i.capitalize()`. Both functions do not change the initial value but return a copy of it: [`lower()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_lower.htm), [`capitalize()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_capitalize.htm)

Comment: thanks it worked, pretty stupid question of mine, i'm still new to programmming. Thaks a lot anyway

Comment: [No such thing as a stupid question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_such_thing_as_a_stupid_question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python list comprehensions are good for this:

```
titles = ['King ARTHUR', 'Lancelot The brave', 'galahad the  pure', 'Servant  patsy', 'GALAHAD THE PURE']
normalised_titles = [' '.join("the" if w.lower() == 'the' else w.title() for w in title.split()) for title in titles]

print normalised_titles
```

Giving you:

```
['King Arthur', 'Lancelot the Brave', 'Galahad the Pure', 'Servant Patsy', 'Galahad the Pure']
```

The aim here is to first use `split()` to produce a list of words without any extra spaces. For each word use `title()` to make the first character a capital unless it is the word `the` in which case keep it lowercase. Finally, join all the words back together with a space between each using `join()`.